# Python regex to check if a substring is at the beginning or at the end of a bigger path to look for

Tags: python, regex

I have a string containing words in the form `word1_word2, word3_word4, word5_word1` (so a word can appear at the left or at the right). I want a regex that looks for all the occurrences of a specific word, and returns the "super word" containing it. So if I'm looking for `word1`, I expect my regex to return `word1_word2, word5_word1`. Since the word can appear on the left or on the right, I wrote this:

```
re.findall("( {}_)?[\u0061-\u007a\u00e0-\u00e1\u00e8-\u00e9\u00ec\u00ed\u00f2-\u00f3\u00f9\u00fa]*(_{} )?".format("w1", "w1"), string)
```

With the optional blocks at the beginning or at the end of the pattern. However, it takes forever to execute and I think something is not correct because I tried removing the optional blocks and writing two separate regex for looking at the beginning and at the end and they are much faster (but I don't want to use two regex). Am I missing something or is it normal?

Comment: can you add your string?

Comment: Do you have to use regex for this?

Comment: @TalFolkman It is a very huge string containing more than 800k couples in the format I described. Each couple is the key of a dictionary. I merged everything into a string for this purpose

Comment: @3therk1ll I'm not forced to, but I think this might be the case where regex are the most efficient way to do so. I don't know what else I could do, other than scanning the dictionary keys but it would take a lot of time since I would have to repeat the scan for each word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the regex solution to your problem:

```py
re.findall(rf'\b({yourWord}_\w+?|\w+?_{yourWord})\b', yourString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python provides some methods to do this

```
a=['word1_word2', 'word3_word4', 'word5_word1']

b = [x for x in a if x.startswith("word1") or x.endswith('word1')]
print(b) # ['word1_word2', 'word5_word1']
```

Referenece [link](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/endswith.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'word1_word2, word3_word4, word5_word1'

matches = re.finditer(r'(\w+_word1)|(word1_\w+)', s)
result = list(map(lambda x: x.group(), matches))
['word1_word2', 'word5_word1']
```

This is one method, but seeing @Carl his answer I voted for his. That is a faster and cleaner method. I will just leave it here as one of many regex options.

Answer (score 0):

this regex will do the job for word1:

```
regex = (word\d_)*word1(_word\d)*
re.findall(regex, string)
```

you can also use this:

```
re.findall(rf'\b(word{number}_\w+?|\w+?_word{number})\b', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex.

In the following, replace `word1` with the word you're looking for. This is assuming that the word you are looking for consists of only alphanumeric characters.

```regex
([a-zA-Z0-9]*_word1)|(word1_.[a-zA-Z0-9]*)
```